# Is there an idiom for join() with a head or tail?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

''.join(list) is pretty great. However, I'm noticing that I very commonly have to add additional characters to the beginning and end. I've done this in a few ways, but it feels like there's a more readable way that I can't think of.

Is there an elegant way of handling it? Am I just over-thinking this?

For example:

```
["column1", "column2", "column3"]
```

Desired output:

```
 | column1 | column2 | column3 |
```

Code without beginning and end (concise!)

```
print ' | '.join(mylist)
```

With head and tail:

```
print ' | ' + ' | '.join(mylist) + ' | '
print ' | ', ' | '.join(mylist), ' | '
print " | {} | ".format(' | '.join(mylist))
print ' | '.join([''] + mylist + ['']) (ugh)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a better way than the approaches you found already. Here's my preference, fixing an error where you introduced an extra space at the beginning and the end:

```
print ' |' + ' | '.join(list) + '| '
```

What makes you uncomfortable about this?  Is it readability?  Having to repeat yourself when you generate the same string in different places?  If so, the answer to both of those is to package this line as a function, and have the callers use that.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to package as a function - that's the true Python way.

Comment: Good call on the function - and for the reminder that even tiny snippets of code should be tested before being posted...

Answer (score 3):

I think the third option is the closet you can get:

```
print " | {} | ".format(' | '.join(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
" | " + "".join(x + " | " for x in lst)
```

I don't think there's a single "nice" way to do this. If you need this a lot, write a function to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one line:

```
print "| %s |" % (' | '.join(list))
```

But probably overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra empty strings at the beginning and the end of the list may allow you to join without "repeating yourself" -- you can still change the separator by changing one character.

```
" | ".join([""] + lst + [""])
```

Or to avoid making a temporary list if `lst` is large:

```
from itertools import chain
" | ".join(chain([""], lst, [""])
```